Tabbar indicator not chaning in flutter
In design, Tabbar is being used and on Expand button, build Media is being passed in MaterialPageRoute, Some bool variables are being used to disable view and tab when they are not available. On expanding while changing the tab indicator not getting changed appear disable on selection, I tried creating new tabbar for expand button still the same issue.
 Widget _buildTab({bool showInModal = false}) {
        if(showInModal){
          _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
        }

    return ignoreImage && ignoreVideo && ignoreB2B && ignoreCertificate
        ? Container()
        : DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,
            child: TabBar(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
              isScrollable: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  height: 30,
                  // text: "Image",
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      'Image',
                      style: ignoreImage ? ignoreStyle : const TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      'Video',
                      style: ignoreVideo ? ignoreStyle : const TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      'B2B Sparkle',
                      style: ignoreB2B ? ignoreStyle : const TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      'Certificate',
                      style:
                          ignoreCertificate ? ignoreStyle : const TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              onTap: (index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  if (photoUrlList.isNotEmpty) {
                    tabIndexValueNotifier.value = index;
                    leftArrowIndicatorValueNotifier.value = 0;
                    rightArrowIndicatorValueNotifier.value = 0;
                    photoNameValueNotifier.value = 0;
                    rightArrowIndicatorValueNotifier.notifyListeners();
                    leftArrowIndicatorValueNotifier.notifyListeners();
                  } else {
                    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                      _tabController.index = _tabController.previousIndex;
                    } else {
                      return;
                    }
                  }
                } else if (index == 1) {
                  if (!ignoreVideo) {
                    tabIndexValueNotifier.value = index;
                    webVideoKey.currentState?.reloadWebView();
                  } else {
                    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                      _tabController.index = _tabController.previousIndex;
                    } else {
                      return;
                    }
                  }
                } else if (index == 2) {
                  if (!ignoreB2B) {
                    tabIndexValueNotifier.value = index;
                    webB2bKey.currentState?.reloadWebView();
                  } else {
                    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                      _tabController.index = _tabController.previousIndex;
                    } else {
                      return;
                    }
                  }
                } else if (index == 3) {
                  if (certificateUrlList.isNotEmpty) {
                    tabIndexValueNotifier.value = index;
                  } else {
                    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                      _tabController.index = _tabController.previousIndex;
                    } else {
                      return;
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  tabIndexValueNotifier.value = index;
                }
              },
            ),
          );
  }

_buildMedia Method
 Widget _buildMedia(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool isShownInModal = false,
  }) {
    final effectivePageViewController = isShownInModal
        ? PageController(initialPage: photoNameValueNotifier.value)
        : mediaPageViewController;

    return ignoreImage && ignoreVideo && ignoreB2B && ignoreCertificate
        ? Container(
            height: 350,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: CoreColor.neutral100,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            ),
            child: Center(child: Assets.coreSvgs.imagePlaceholder.svg()),
          )
        : SizedBox(
            height: isShownInModal ? null : 320,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildTab(showInModal: true),
                Expanded(
                  child: BlocBuilder<DiamondAssetInteractiveCubit,
                      DiamondAssetInteractiveState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (context, constraints) {
                          return ValueListenableBuilder(
                            valueListenable: tabIndexValueNotifier,
                            builder: (context, value, _) {
                              if (value == 0) {
                                return _buildPhotoView(
                                  context,
                                  effectivePageViewController,
                                  isShownInModal: isShownInModal,
                                );
                              } else if (value == 1) {
                                return _buildVideoWebView(
                                  isShownInModal,
                                  constraints,
                                );
                              } else if (value == 2) {
                                return _buildB2BWebView(
                                    isShownInModal, constraints);
                              } else if (value == 3) {
                                return _buildCertificateView(
                                  context,
                                  effectivePageViewController,
                                  isShownInModal: isShownInModal,
                                );
                              } else {
                                return const SizedBox();
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

On Expand button
CoreIconButton(
                    tooltip: 'frame',
                    child: const PhosphorIcon(
                      PhosphorIconsRegular.cornersOut,
                      color: CoreColor.neutral900,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      webB2b2Key.currentState?.reloadWebView();
                      final page = MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (newContext) {
                          return Theme(
                            data: CoreTheme.light,
                            child: BlocProvider.value(
                              value:
                                  context.read<DiamondAssetInteractiveCubit>(),
                              child: Scaffold(
                                body: SafeArea(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                    children: [
                                      16.height,
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: context.pop,
                                            child: const PhosphorIcon(
                                              PhosphorIconsRegular.x,
                                              color: CoreColor.neutral900,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const Spacer(),
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 7,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: kScreenPadding,
                                          ),
                                          child: _buildMedia(
                                            newContext,
                                            isShownInModal: true,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      16.height,
                                      photoUrlList.isNotEmpty
                                          ? _buildDotsIndicator()
                                          : Container(),
                                      photoUrlList.isNotEmpty
                                          ? 16.height
                                          : 0.height,
                                      _buildAssetName(),
                                      16.height,
                                      _buildActions(false),
                                      const Spacer(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                      Navigator.of(context).push(page);
                    },
                  )



You need to call _tabController.animateTo(index) in the onTap callback of the TabBar.
onTap: (index) { 
              if (showInModal) {
                _tabController.animateTo(index);
              }
              // your other code here...
            }, 


nah not working
